# Nothing happend after gulp task

Tags: javascript, build, gulp

I have gulp file with simple tasks, like move files from one folder to another and render html from jade. It was working, but today i have problem that tasks run, but nothing happens.

```
     var gulp = require('gulp'),
            plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
            browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
            paths = {};

        paths = {
        src: './app/',
        dest: './build/',
        lib: './lib/',
        assets: './app/assets/'
    };
        gulp.task('fonts', function () {
             return gulp.src(paths.assets + 'fonts/**')
                .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest + 'assets/fonts'));
        });

        gulp.task('images', function () {
             return gulp.src(paths.assets + 'images/**')
                .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest + 'assets/images'));
        });

        gulp.task('scripts', function () {
             return gulp.src(paths.src + '/**/*.js')
                .pipe(plumber())
                .pipe(browserify({shim: require('./browserify-shim')(paths)}))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest + 'assets/scripts/'));
        });

gulp.task('test',['fonts','images','scripts']);
```

I have another project using the same gulpfile and it works fine, but in this project i reinstall gulp, crazy but may be it's a point of the problem.

Comment: try to run `npm install` and re-run gulp task. please, put your gulpfile here for more details

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/800